# непонимаю почему не изменяется функция

Tags: python

```
import os
import time
import keyboard

a = 0
b = 10

while True:
    if keyboard.wait('Ctrl'):
        a = a + b
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(a)
```

на выходе после каждого нажатия cntr должно прибавлятся 10 к а

Answer (score 1):

во первых - не понимаю зачем модуль os, но это ладно

во вторых: если посмотреть что возвращает функция wait можно понять что она ничего не возвращает, т.е. использовать для проверки её бессмысленно, что бы проверить на нажатие надо использовать функцию keyboard.is_pressed

в третьих - a это переменная а не функция